# Post a Tweet using Twitter4J library on a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets, twitter

I'm working on a web mashup for a University project. The thing is that I don't get to post stuff on twitter using the Twitter4J library.

First of all I have a button on a .jsp file coded like that:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="PostTweetController">   
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="req" value="tweet">Tweet this</button>
    </form>
```

With the following servlet mapping on web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>PostTweetController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PostTweetController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>aiss.controller.twitter.PostTweetController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PostTweetController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PostTweetController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

That goes to the PostTweetController.java servlet class I'm trying to code, this is the class with nothing done.

```
package aiss.controller.twitter;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.Configuration;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class IndexSearchController
 */
public class PostTweetController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PostTweetController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */



    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

With other stuff I've already done it is as simple as requesting info to APIs or posting stuff on the doGet method, but in this case I need to authenticate with OAuth and that's why I'm trying to use Twitter4J but I just can't make it work.

I tried this code but nothing happens, I guess it doesn't work on servlets or I'm doing something wrong.

```
String consumerKey = "";
        String consumerSecret = "";
        String accessToken = "";
        String accessSecret = "";

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessSecret);
        String tweet = "Hi";
        try 
        {
           TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
           Twitter twitter = factory.getInstance();

           System.out.println(twitter.getScreenName());
           Status status = twitter.updateStatus(tweet);
           System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
            }catch (TwitterException te) {
               te.printStackTrace();
               System.exit(-1);
            }
```

I also added the required dependencies to pom.xml